# PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") not working on RestController

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-security, uri

I found many similar questions but none has solved my problem my problem is:
PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") not working on my RestController.

my configuration security is:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="
         select login,password,1
         from test tst where tst.login=?" 
                authorities-by-username-query="
         select login,'ROLE_SAVE' from test tst where tst.login=?"
            />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

on my RestController i add this annotation:@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class PrinterController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseStatus test() {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

but not work any user can consume this resource.

Comment: yes i enable it with <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

Comment: Try adding it in `value` attribute : `@PreAuthorize( value="isAuthenticated()")`

Comment: does't work, i have the same problem

Comment: How the bean's container discover your configuration? In your application you have a servlet configuration (part of the web context) and you have the application context (or the root context) which contains persistence configuration, security configuration, etc...

Comment: Edit your post and add it, it will be clearer to read !

Comment: and in my applicationContext i add this line: 
<!-- Security -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/security.xml" />

Comment: this is my web xml file 
~<filter> <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> <filter-class> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy </filter-class> </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain </filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> <init-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value> classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext.xml </param-value> </init-param>~

Answer (score 14):

### 2024 Spring Security 6

You need to add the following annotation to your Security Configuration class:

```
@EnableMethodSecurity()
```

`prePostEnabled` is turned on by default.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableMethodSecurity.html

### 2018 Answer

You need to add the following annotation to your Security Configuration class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Thanks to this article:

https://nixmash.com/post/spring-mvc-method-security-with-preauthorize-and-sp-el

Answer (score -1):

after remplacing `@PreAuthorize` by `@Secured` and add `secured-annotations="enabled"` in security xml file the problem is fixed.

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

on my RestController

```
@Secured
```